# facebook share og:url overrides data taken from og:title

Tags: javascript, facebook

I have a page on my website which is located at:  `www.mywebsite.com/share/id`
This website has the following tags:

```
    <meta property="og:url" content="https://www.mywebsite.com/catalog">
    <meta property="og:title" content="I just bought something">
    <meta property="og:description" content="This is your bought item">
```

The page has an achor tag with a link to `http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=www.mywebsite.com/share/id'` which when pressed, it opens a Facebook Share dialog

I would like the FB share dialog to load the title, description and the url from the og tags, the url in the og:url should be the link to the page appearing on the FB share dialog.

The problem is that instead of doing that, the FB share dialog takes it's data from the url located in the OG:URL meta tag and ignore the og:title and og:description which was supplied

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, `og:url` tells Facebook **scraper** to ignore any meta data in this page and load meta data from `og:url` instead. See [A Guide to Sharing for Webmasters](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters)

Comment: So `og:url` should be same as `?url=shareUrl`;